# What is the difference between the infinitive and present participle?

Tags: differences, gerund-vs-infinitive

I already know the difference between "stop doing something" and "stop to do something".

I really don't know what is the difference between "like doing something" and "like to do something".

And is it "gerund" or "present participle"?

---

This is not a duplicate question. That answer doesn't fit (in my opinion) to this question. Actually, I want to know the difference between saying, for example: *"I like to drink soda"* and *"I like drinking soda"*, and which is the correct if there is a correct construction.

Comment: [That answer](http://english.stackexchange.com/a/61558/15299) only applies to _try_; _stop_ and _like_ have predictably different syntax. So it's not a duplicate at all. [This answer](http://english.stackexchange.com/a/50592/15299) deals with _stop,_ and _like_ can take either an infinitive [complement](http://www.umich.edu/~jlawler/complements.pdf) (_I like to ski_) or a [gerund complement](http://www.umich.edu/~jlawler/aue/gerund.html) (_I like skiing_) with no change in meaning. It's always about the predicates; different predicates have different rules.

Comment: Thank you for the help, John Lawler. And it is not a duplicate of a question about "try", it's about "like".

Comment: @John: Yes, but are there any *general* principles that go beyond simply saying "it depends on the specific verb"?

Comment: You might find [some here](http://english.stackexchange.com/a/110798/15299), but they're only "speaking roughly"

Answer (score 0):

The short answer is, there is no difference between the two 'like' constructions. They mean the same thing and which one you use would depend on context/preference/custom.

> I like doing crosswords / I like to do crosswords

I don't know of any rule that would help explain this construction when used with other verbs.

These are not gerunds (a noun formed from a verb): *doing* is the participle, and *to do* is the infinitive.

However, 'doing something' is often a general term standing in for another verb, so it might depend on the construction of that other verb.

> A: "I like **walking** early in the morning when it's not so busy."
>  B:  "Yes I like **doing**
>   that too."
>
> A:  "I like **to wind** down with a glass of wine when I get home in the
>   evening."
>  B:  "Yes I like **to do** that too."

**Edit:**
Re Gerunds, please see John Lawler's comments below.

Comment: No, they are gerunds. _Doing_ is the present active participle form of _do_; [that form has a number of uses](http://www.umich.edu/~jlawler/aue/gerund.html), including gerund verb forms. Gerund is one of the possible complements of verbs.

Comment: @JohnLawler Thanks for the link but I am puzzled as to how this is a gerund. Which section is the relevant one? None of the examples seems the same as the construction here.

Comment: _Like_ can take four different types of [complement clauses](http://www.umich.edu/~jlawler/complements.pdf): gerund clause with EQUI _He likes skiing_; infinitive clause with EQUI _He likes to ski_; tensed clause with extraposition _He likes (it) that it rarely rains here_; tensed embedded question clause _He likes what you're doing_. A gerund clause has an untensed _-ing_ verb form, an infinitive clause has an untensed infinitive verb form, and tensed clauses have tensed verb forms. That's all.

Comment: @JohnLawler I bow to superior knowledge, I've added an edit.