# the first trial <stemming/to stem> from... vs. the first person to climb

Tags: infinitives, present-participles

Here are excerpts from different American news articles:

> a. Mr. Manafort’s case is separate from the investigation into Russia’s interference in the 2016 election and any ties to the Trump campaign, though this is **the first trial stemming from the investigation of Robert S. Mueller III, the special counsel**. ([The New York Times](https://www.nytimes.com/2018/08/07/us/politics/manafort-trial-gates-testimony.html))
>
> b. On Wednesday — nearly 13 months to the day after the Justice Department announced the arrests of 10 men, including four assistant coaches, as part of an ongoing investigation of corruption in college basketball — **the first trial to stem from the probe** resulted in a victory for federal prosecutors and the FBI. ([The Washington Post](https://www.washingtonpost.com/sports/colleges/whats-next-for-basketball-black-market-investigation-and-what-it-might-mean/2018/10/25/491eeb28-d862-11e8-a10f-b51546b10756_story.html?utm_term=.99975b3d8627))

They both contain a noun phrase (shown in boldface), and the noun phrase has the structure of either 'the first trial stemming from...' or 'the first trial to stem from...'

So both versions seem to be well formed.

If so, why is it that you can't use '-ing' instead of 'to infinitive' in the following sentences?

'Practical English Usage' by Swan says:

> Superlatives can be followed by an infinitive structure. The meaning is similar
>   to an identifying relative clause (see 495).
>
> *He's **the oldest athlete ever to win an Olympic gold medal**.*
>
> (= ... who has ever won ...)
>
> This structure is also common with *first*, *second*, *third* etc, *next*, *last* and *only*.
>
> *Who was **the first person to climb Everest without oxygen**?*
>
> ***The next to arrive*** was Mrs Patterson.
>
> *She's **the only scientist to have won three Nobel prizes**.*

Comment: Search "gerund versus infinitive" right here in this site. Good Luck.

Comment: @Kris I wish that would answer my question.

Comment: It's a bit mushy, but "climbing" implies an on-going process.

Comment: @HotLicks What do you mean it's a bit mushy? And are you saying 'climbing' doesn't work, because it implies an on-going process? If so, why doesn't 'stemming' imply the same on-going process?

Comment: @listeneva - Actually, "stemming" does imply an on-going process, but the "on-goingness" of it may have been in the past.  Like I said, it's mushy -- the "rules" are more intuitive than reasoned.

Comment: @HotLicks I think it's languages, not rules, that are more intuitive than reasoned. Rules are there to help a language look more reasoned than intuitive. If your 'rule' can't do that, I think you should doubt your rule.

Comment: @listeneva - Which why I said "rules" in quotes.  In many cases they are merely "guidelines", with multiple exceptions.

Comment: The infinitive *to stem* is used only in a different sense of the word *stem* - as in *to stem the tide of*. I suspect it just clues us in to which word is being used. Of course it appears following another verb in the normal way - seems to stem from, appears to stem from, but I could not find a single example of "NOUN to stem from".

Comment: @PhilSweet Here's a counterexample: _On Wednesday — nearly 13 months to the day after the Justice Department announced the arrests of 10 men, including four assistant coaches, as part of an ongoing investigation of corruption in college basketball — the first trial to stem from the probe resulted in a victory for federal prosecutors and the FBI._ https://wapo.st/2WPd11h

Comment: @listeneva Nice find. Ngrams won't accept 4 word strings with a  _NOUN_  wildcard. So I ran "_NOUN_ to stem" and no occurances matched this type of stem. Then I searched for specific nouns using the results from "_NOUN_ stemming from" and got zip.

Comment: A common meme that uses the _ing-form_ after what Swan calls superlatives is: _Will the last person leaving Seattle turn out the lights_.   Other Google examples include: _The first student sitting in their seat will get a treat_ and _The last person standing up with no chair to sit down in, gets the ball._ It seems that the _ing-form_ can be used for actions that are or will be in progress and is problematic in contexts where the action has completed: _?The last person standing up got the ball._ If I have time I will pursue this line of thought.

Comment: @Shoe Thanks. Can't _The last person standing up got the ball_ mean "The last person who were standing up got the ball"? If it can, it should work as well. Now, the problem is, _It was the first trial stemming from the Russia investigation_ I think means "It was the first trial that stemmed from the Russia investigation". Isn't this a completed action?

Comment: @listeneva. You are right that the standing example could be understood as _the last person who is/was standing up_, but _standing up_ seems like an action to me, not the state of _standing_. The source of this quote does not fully resolve whether it's action or state: https://www.hockeyalberta.ca/uploads/source/Coaching_Resources/Coach_Education/Team_Building_Activities.pdf. As for _stemming_, it seems to me that if something stems from something else, then it will continue to do so into eternity. _Stemming_ is therefore not a completed action.

Comment: @Shoe Do you think that the sentence means "It was the first trial that were stemming from the Russia investigation"? As far as I know, 'stem from' cannot be in the progressive aspect.

Comment: Yes, but verbs that are typically not used in continuous phrases (eg. _is belonging / was stemming_) can be used in ing-form in reduced relative clauses. Eg.  _A school book belonging to Beatles legend Sir Paul McCartney has sold at auction for £46,800._ (https://www.msn.com/en-sg/entertainment/celebrity/paul-mccartneys-school-book-sells-for-%C2%A346800/ar-BBViXQX)

Comment: @Shoe But _belonging_ in your example is reduced not from "that is belonging" but from "that belongs". That is, it carries no progressive aspect.

Comment: True, but I'll leave it to the experts on this site to say whether _belonging to Paul McCartney_ can be classified as a _reduced relative_ here. As to the climbing example, it seems that _climbing Everest_ in Swan's example implies getting to the top, i.e. completing the action. But climbing is also _being in the process of going up_, in which case the _ing-form_ seems possible. Imagine an obstacle course, part of which is a wall: _John was the first person climbing the wall, but Matt was first over it_.

Comment: @Shoe Excellent point! Thanks for your insight. I'll have to think it over.

Comment: @Shoe How about this? In _the first trial stemming from the investigation_, _stemming_ cannot be interpreted as having a progressive aspect simply because 'stem from' cannot be used in the progressive aspect. Thus, even the participle form can only mean a completed action, so it's allowed.

Comment: @Shoe But _the first person knowing the truth..._ doesn't seem to work, does it?

Comment: Point 1 (_stemming_): It seems simply to be the case that relative clauses containing (what I will call here) non-progressive verbs (e.g. _that stems from, which belongs to, who hates_) can be reduced to their _ing-form_. Google example: _Anyone hating any genre of music  generally doesn't know the context in which it's meant to be enjoyed_.

Comment: Point 2 (_knowing_): It seems to me that you either know something or you don't - it's not a process. _Read_ is a similar verb to _climb_. Out of context, _I read (past tense) the book_ can mean _I spent time reading it_ or _I finished reading it_. I usually start my lessons with a period of SSR (sustained silent reading) and often say something like: "_The first student reading will be the first to leave for lunch_", which exemplifies the two constructions you are asking about.

Comment: @Shoe Does this work? _She was the first person hating the genre of music_. // If you intended (as you say) _The first student reading_ to mean "The first person who  finishes reading", I think it should be _The first student to read_.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/92249/discussion-between-shoe-and-listeneva).

Comment: @listeneva - It would be grammatically correct to say, 'He's the oldest athlete ever to win an Olympic gold medal [while] wearing gold lame.' In this case the v+-ing form can be interpreted either as an adjectival phrase modifying the noun or an adverbial phrase modifying 'win'. Look at your question from this angle and see if that helps. There may be a link to stative verbs - I'll think about this a bit more.

Comment: @LeonConrad Thanks for your comment. Would it be possible to say this? _He's the oldest athlete wearing gold lame._

Comment: Per Swan, the line in the *Times* article **would** be considered incorrect, but that's just a prescriptivist position.  Personally, I think "the first trial to stem" is the best-sounding construction in either case, but that's just my opinion, and Swan's, but not some people at the *Times* at a particular point in time.

Comment: What is the name of the section in the Swan book you quote from? In my copy of Swan (Third edition) neither section 495 nor page 495 has the sentences you include.

Comment: @Shoe It's section 284. (Bottom of page 259)

Comment: @KannE What's the 'due to' answer got anything to do with the current question?

Comment: @listeneva - the implication of 'He's the oldest athlete wearing gold lamé' is that there is a group of athletes, a sub-group of athletes wearing gold lamé, and that sub-group is ranked by age. I believe it to be correct and equivalent to 'He's the oldest of the athletes who are wearing gold lamé.'

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To summarize the question:

> We can say *the first trial **stemming** from* as well as  *the first
>   trial **to stem** from*. So why can't we say *the first person
>   **climbing** Mount Everest* as well as *the first person **to climb** Mount Everest*?

In Swan's examples each verb (*win, climb, arrive*) is what Quirk et al.  in *A Comprehensive Grammar Of The English Language* p201 (henceforth just Quirk) would classify, according to a complex verb tree, as: *Dynmamic > Durative > Conclusive > Agentive > Accomplishment*.

One of the verbs that Quirk lists as falling into the above category is *write*. An example of *write* as a *conclusive/accomplishment* (using one of Swan's *the oldest/first/only, etc* constructions) is:

- Matt was the only child to write a 'thank you' letter (*i.e. conclude or accomplish the action of writing it*).

Swan's sentence *Who was the first person to climb Everest without oxygen?* will most likely be similarly interpreted as the *accomplishment* of getting to the top of the mountain.

These two sentences can be expanded to use the past simple in a relative clause:

- Matt was the only child **who wrote** a 'thank you' letter.
- Who was the first person **who climbed** Everest without oxygen?

But Quirk also lists *write* in another category, namely: *Dynamic > Durative > Nonconclusive > Agentive > Activities*.

An example of *write* in this category is:

- Matt was the only child writing at the end of the test (*i.e. the focus is on the nonconclusive nature of an action in progress*).

Similarly, it is possible to imagine a context using Swan's *the first person + climb* example where the focus is on the *activity* rather than the *accomplishment*. For example, describing an obstacle race:

- Mae was the first person climbing the wall, but Ximena was first over it.

These two sentences can be expanded as:

- Matt was the only child **who was** writing at the end of the test.
- Mae was the first person **who was** climbing the wall, but Ximena was first over it.

Another verb that falls into both the *conclusive/accomplishment* and the *nonconclusive activity* categories is *read*:

- Emiko was the first student to read *Great Expectations* (*i.e. accomplish the task, reading it to the end*).
- Emiko was the first student reading at the beginning of class (*i.e. to get out her book and start reading*).

So, in summary, the answer to the question *why is it that you can't use '-ing' instead of 'to infinitive' in the following sentences?* is:

> You can, for *climb* and other verbs which fall into both the two categories listed by Quirk, where the focus is respectively on the *conclusive/accomplishment* nature of the verb in context or on its *nonconclusive/activity* nature.

---

**Further thoughts**

The OP states of the two trial texts that use the *-ing* form and *to-infinitive* form of *stem* respectively: *'both versions seem to be well-formed*'. This seems to be the case for me too. However, it raises an interesting issue.

If we expand the *-ing* form in *This is the first trial stemming from the investigation of Robert S. Mueller* in a similar way as above, we get:

**This is the first trial that is stemming from the investigation of Robert S. Mueller*.

But *stem* in this sense of the word is a non-progressive verb, so the expansion results in an ungrammaticality. In other words, *This is the first trial stemming from the investigation* cannot be regarded as a reduction in the same way as *the first person climbing* is a reduction from *the person person who is/was climbing*.

There is a discussion of this phenomenon in the chapter on *Relative Clauses* in *The Grammar Book: An ESL / EFL Teacher's Course* (p597):

> **Participles that do not derive from relative clauses**
>
> Our discussion of this topic is incomplete unless we point out that
>   there are also adjectival *-ing* participles that could not possibly
>   be accounted for via the pronoun + *be* deletion rule. Recall that
>   verbs which are stative rather than dynamic rarely take the
>   progressive aspect, yet stative verbs can and do occur as adjectival
>   participles:
>
> - Max built an additional room, measuring 12 by 12 feet.
>
> This *-ing* particple cannot be derived from a reduced relative
>   clause:
>
> - *Max built an additional room, which is measuring 12 by 12 feet.
>
> How to account for the structure of such adjectival participles
>   remains an unsolved problem in need of further research.

Note: that  *The Cambridge Grammar Of The English Language* (CGEL, p446) does not use the term *reduced relative clause* for  *-ing* constructions such as above. They are classified under *Post head modifiers > non-finite gerund-participial clauses*. Example: *People living near the site will be seriously disadvantaged.*

And one last point, the CGEL (p118) has a simplified version of the Quirk's verb classification tree mentioned above, but includes the terms *telic* and *atelic* as follows: _ *Accomplishments [telic]* and *Activities [atelic]*. There is a discussion of these terms on *ThoughtCo*: [telicity (verbs)](https://www.thoughtco.com/telicity-verbs-1692459).

Comment: I don't have access to any books cited here. But under Quirk's classification, the verb 'stem' doesn't seem to belong to "Accomplishments" or "Activities", because both these are subsumed under 'Dynamic' whereas 'stem' is a stative verb. So are you saying that a stative verb can be either -ing or to-infinitive after 'superlative/first/second...etc + noun', and that a dynamic verb indicating an accomplishment should be to-infinitive after 'superlative/first/second...etc + noun' whereas a dynamic verb indicating an activity should be -ing after 'superlative/first/second...etc + noun'?

Comment: @KannE I'm sure the asterisk indicates that the sentence is ungrammatical.

Comment: @KannE Yes, a nice answer, although I personally think that the issue of reducing a relative clause is a red herring.

Comment: @listeneva. Quirk would classify _stem_ in this sense under: _Stative > State_. As to the second sentence of your first comment above, your summary of my position applies to _stem_ and _climb_, but without further investigation I would not want to make the bold claim that all stative verbs can take both forms as _stem_ does in this context. Maybe you could ask this as a separate question because I don't have a lot of time today to pursue this in depth in comments.

Comment: @listeneva. Your question in essence was why can't we say _the first person climbing_? In order to show that we can indeed say that in certain contexts it was important to show how _climbing_ can be considered as reduced from _was/was climbing_. In my _further thoughts_ I covered the supplementary issue that arose in the comments in respect of the present participle of _stative verbs_ such as _stem_. I thought the quote from _The Grammar Book_ was useful to show that _measuring/stemming_ cannot in those sentences be regarded as reductions in the same way as in the climbing example.

Comment: @KannE. _listeneva_ is right. The asterisk at the beginning of a sentence indicates that the sentence is  considered ungrammatical. A question mark at the beginning indicates _dubious grammaticality_.

Comment: I wonder if your two examples _Matt was the only child **writing** at the end of the test_ and _Mae was the first person **climbing** the wall, but Ximena was first over it_ can be expanded respectively as _Matt was the only child **who wrote** at the end of the test_ and _Mae was the first person **who climbed** the wall, but Ximena was first over it_.

Answer (score 2):

Your last examples happen to use an expression that almost always is followed by an infinitive form.

The phrase "first person" in this syntax suggests that the following clause will describe a completed action. While a present participle could conceivably be used and understood, sticking to the infinitive both fits common usage and avoids complications from suggesting a [continuous or progressive sense](https://www.ef.edu/english-resources/english-grammar/present-participle/). For example, "the first person climbing Everest" might make sense in some contexts, like if that person were climbing Everest at the moment the statement was made, or if reference were being made to that moment of climbing in the past. Otherwise the participle form is context-locked in a way the to-infinitive isn't. More generally, "the first person (+infinitive)" is a common expression, and almost always takes a to-infinitive. Searches confirm how common it is. [The Corpus of Contemporary American English](https://www.english-corpora.org/coca/) gives 822 results for "first person to" and 8 results for "first person (-ing form of verb)." The British National Corpus gives 109 results for "first person to" and no results for "first person (-ing form of verb)."

> He was the first person to climb Everest without oxygen.

This is not the same as a situation where the infinitive form and the present participle are both valid. In these situations, either form of *climb* is acceptable; the verb minimizes the distinction between the infinitive and the participle form such that either an atemporal sense or a continuous sense describe what's being *tried* or *liked* (see previous Stack Exchange questions [1](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/159227/what-is-the-difference-between-the-infinitive-and-present-participle) and [2](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/61552/try-to-save-or-try-saving)):

> He tried to climb Everest.
>
> He tried climbing Everest.
>
> He likes to climb Everest.
>
> He likes climbing Everest.

So why does *stemming* and *to stem* work in the examples above? First, it's not attached to the same expression as "the first person" or some other personal form, so it need not conform to the same pattern in usage.

Second, all of your latter examples have personal subjects, and the infinitive verb describes the action that the person takes. There's nothing in the description that precludes a participle instead of an infinitive, but the infinitive may better capture the idea that the action is completed. In contrast, with "first trial," the verb form is describing something about this trial. The verb "stem," like "belong," "involve," and "pertain," primarily describes the trial's relationship to something else. These relationship verbs can appear in either infinitive or participle form. COCA confirms this, giving 8 results each for both "first trial to" and "first trial (-ing form of verb)."

Comment: The 'common idiom' link does refer to an idiom, but that idiom is not exactly the same meaning as my example.

Comment: Also, I don't think that describing an 'accomplishment' has anything to do with requiring a to-infinitive and banning a participle after the noun. For example, I don't think this describes an accomplishment: _Tom Hardy Was the First Person to Know About My Engagement_ https://www.esquire.com/lifestyle/sex/a22697034/tom-hardy-esquire-engagement/

Comment: There's [a pragmatic difference](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/61558/15299) between _try `V`-ing_ and _try to `V`_.

Comment: @JohnLawler Yes! I already link to that answer in my post.

Comment: @JohnLawler I don't know how the 'try V'/'try to V' distinction is any relevant in the current question.

Comment: @KannE I agree that the so-called 'relationship verbs' can be an exception to Swan's rule cited in the OP. But I have no way of knowing if they are the only exception or simply one of many exceptions to the rule, because even this answer fails to formulate the reasoning behind the exceptional treatment.

Comment: @listeneva What kind of reasoning do you expect? Language usage doesn't always follow neat logical rules, and it'd take work far beyond the reward offered here to flesh out (a) exactly what makes "relationship verbs" usable with this construction when other verbs usually aren't and (b) whether other exceptions exist.

Comment: @KannE Thanks! My post is perhaps more process than product, and it's hard to find the time to come back to it and clarify. The intermediary parts were helpful for me to think through why parallel situations with interchangeable infinitive/participles aren't like this. That helped me see that at least one class of verbs  would allow for either infinitive or participle. I'm not sure it's even the verb itself that's important, but rather its function: it's not qualifying "the first trial to do something," but describing more context about the trial. That's hard to support though.